# Should I consider maximum power or typical power when I select LED power?

Tags: power, datasheet, watts, maximum-ratings

I have datasheet:

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/635258/OPTOSUPPLY/OSI3XNE3E1E.html

There is maximum power which is 2 W and typical which is maybe 1.19.

So the LED is 2 W or approximately 1 W?

And another question:
Its safe to work on maximum rating power which is 2 W?

Comment: How will you cool it?

Comment: @Audioguru heat sink

Comment: Where did the 1.19 watt figure come from?

Comment: 2 W is the absolute max power dissipation. Don’t operate there.

Comment: Constant  typical power is 1.7W.. keep the current 1A is important, various voltage is because of some technological differences. So

Comment: @Andyaka typical voltage 1.7v  x typical current 700mA =1.19w /p=v*i

Answer (score 0):

2W is the absolute maximum power dissipation. If you hit or exceed this limit, you should worry about permanently breaking the LED.

The forward voltage is specified based on a forward current of 700mA. If you use this LED and you set the current to 700mA, you may expect a forward voltage about 1.7V, usually, but sometimes up to 2.0V. If the current is higher, the voltage will be higher. If the current is lower, the voltage will be lower. A good datasheet would show this on a chart - this one does not.

If you want to set it and forget it, you can design for 700mA and 1.7V-up-to-2.0V. If you need the LED to last for a really, really long time, you might choose to use less current. If you need a bit more light and don't care about maximum lifetime, you could increase the current. (Beware that you may hit the 2W limit before the 1A limit)

If you are daring, you might even increase it above the absolute maximum. There's no LED police going to come and arrest you, after all. The only risk is that you may break the LED or burn yourself through overheating. Many projects do use parts out of spec, but you're entirely on your own, as the manufacturer gives you no guarantees at all. Better to use the recommended numbers if you want your project to work reliably and last a long time. Some people pour liquid nitrogen on their CPUs to break speed records - if the computer still works after the record is broken, it's a success.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one limitation on what current you can run the LED at.

Most likely, you'll be limited by thermal considerations to a current much less than the absolute maximum if you want the LED to last. Note that the 'Absolute maximum' is given at Ta = 25°C so you should derate that for elevated temperature and then derate it some more because running at absolute maximum will lead to poor reliability.

If you are figuring the dissipation to 'size' the heatsink, you should use the maximum forward voltage so any inaccuracy will be conservative.

Some manufacturers such as Lumileds supply detailed design information (many pages of charts and words) to assist in the thermal design process. This manufacturer has [very limited information](https://www.optosupply.com/uppic/file/20160811/14709117072586530.pdf) of that type available (but still more than what is on the datasheet):

[image]

I'm also not sure it helps all that much.